# Inserting Chapters / Cue Points / Bookmarks DURING video capture

Tags: software-rec, video-editing, video-capture, camcorder

I'm interested in using a camcorder to capture several hours of video footage to a computer.  The overwhelming majority of the footage will be totally useless, and so I anticipate it being somewhat of a pain to search through and extract the good bits.  Since I will be present during the capture, I suppose I could just jot down the time whenever something interesting happens.  Still, I wonder about whether some type of video capture software could accomplish this more elegantly: I envision clicking a button to create some type of navigational anchor that I can easily return to when I review the footage.  Note that the whole point would be to create this chapter marker DURING the video capture, not afterwards (which I realize is possible with such software as MetaX).

I'm using the term "chapter" kind of loosely here - I'm not necessarily interested in saving the footage as, say, a DivX file with its standard chapter marking metadata.  Just so long as I can indicate to the software "I want to take a closer look at this frame later," that will cut it for me.

Interested in either Windows or OSX software solutions.  I suppose I'd also be curious to hear about camcorders that accomplish something like what I describe.  It seems that Samsung's "My Clips" feature sort of does this, but I think you're only able to review saved clips from within the camcorder interface, which is not ideal for my purposes.